# How do I beat "...Not as I do"?

Tags: vvvvvv

I simply can't figure this one out.  It's hard enough without trying to get Vermilion across, but with him...?  How do I do it?
[image: A room named "...Not as I Do". Three platforms rise up and down in a pit of spikes. Vermilion and Viridian are standing off to the side on the left.]

Comment: I am currently stuck on this frickin' level right now.  I've figured out HOW to do it, I just...can't frickin' do it consistently.  (I've gotten through a couple of times only to die trying to leave the room myself!)

Comment: @Shin Practice makes perfect!  :P

Comment: Two hours should be enough x.X

Comment: Prepare to get a lot more frustrated still!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzdxX4-9j9U) video shows you how to do it:

Comment: Oh wow...that looks hard... +1!

Comment: I haven't played the game, so out of curiosity: Why did the light-blue character have to go to the little space below the exit and then back again?

Comment: @Tim: The red character follows the blue one but only when the blue one isn't upside down.  So you cross upside down, and flip at the right times to get the red one across.  You control the blue one, but not the red one.

Comment: Oh and @Tim, if you haven't bought it, I would recommend it.  It's part of the [humble bundle](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/08/01/the-humble-bundle/) so you can pay exactly as much as you want for it.

Answer (score 11):

This level *is* annoying. Here's what you must do:

- Get below the first platform while it's up.
- Quickly flip onto the second.
- Before Vermillion has a chance, quickly flip below the third platform.
- As the platform is about to crush you, walk right onto the ledge.
- Walk until you can flip up and down safely.
- Now quickly tap up twice to make Vermillion move onto the next platform until he's safely reached his destination and reached the opposite edge of the level.
- Now you must backtrack again through all three platforms to reach the starting point. You'll want to approach the platforms in the same way you did on your first trip. This'll end you on the leftmost edge, upside down, with Vermillion not following you. This'll give you some peace of mind as you prepare for the final step.
- Walk onto the three platforms like Vermillion did, then join him and move along.

Comment: I prefer the video method in the other answer, since you don't have to worry about your buddy moving at all.  This works, though.

Comment: It's the same method, except described in words

Comment: @AndréTerra No, the difference is the second and third bullet points. The video doesn't flip but just walks across all three platforms upside down.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I stand corrected, you're absolutely right. I, too, prefer the method in the video.

Answer (score 4):

I took 264 deaths, the most in any room of the game, to do it. Vermillion follows the blue but he maintains a particular distance from the blue one. Hence, go to the right edge of floor and turn upside down, then jump to the left edge of 1st moving tile, such that the Vermillion don't leaves the floor. Then move to the right edge of the 1st moving tile, such that tile is exactly at its lowest position and Vermillion jumps on it. Now both, you and Vermillion, are standing on the same tile i.e. the 1st one. Now jump or rather fall on left edge of 2nd moving tile and timely move to its right edge so that Vermillion falls on the 2nd tile. Do the same to reach the third tile and the floor on right side of room.

This method is very easy to perform compared to the flip method which took my 231 lives and still didn't succeed.